# How to print when the key is pressed, it will print something and if not it will print another thing

Tags: c#, while-loop

As the title implies, I want to print the "Outside loop" words when the user doesn't press anything from their keyboard. In the other side, if the user press the Enter button it will print "inside loop" words and break it to end the loop. However, in the end, if the user didn't press anything, the programs will run nothing and when the user press the Enter it will print both words simultaneously.

```
 while(true)
 {
   if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
   {
      Console.WriteLine( "inside loop");
      break;
   }
      Console.WriteLine("outside loop");
 }
```

Current Result :
[image: The Result]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code, post it as code formatted text.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the warn. I made the change, please kindly to check.

Comment: The console input line is blocking. Code that blocks will prevent execution until something happens. Asking for input pauses execution of the current code and awaits keyboard input.

Comment: @Charleh then how do i prevent that? should i use Thread? since Thread able to run 2 things simultaneously, without stopping the program while they were waiting for Input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this will look if a key is pressed and if its the enter key:

```
while (true)
{
    if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("inside loop");
            break;
    }
                
    Console.WriteLine("outside loop");
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for ur code, it works. Can u explain to me, why this code is not expecting and await the user input?

Comment: Sure, Console.ReadKey () is a method that waits for the user to interact with the keyboard, so you're blocking your process. With Console.KeyAvailable you can check beforehand whether a keystroke is available and only read it out if one is actually there.